# How to perform Add, Edit and Delete operations for JSON data using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-1.5

I have the json file:

```
test.json: 

{
    "MyTest": [{
        "Main": {
            "static": {
                "name": "TestName1"
            },
            "dynamic": {
            "testkey01": "testkey01data",
            "testkey02": 40,
            "testkey03vals": [1, 1, 1]
        }}
    }, {
        "Main": {
            "static": {
                "name": "TestName2"
            },"dynamic": {
            "testkey01": "test01value",
            "testkey03": 10,
            "testflags": ["Test"]
        }}
    }, {
        "Main": {
            "static": {
                "name": "TestName3"
            },"dynamic": {
            "testkey01": "testkey01value for TestName3",
            "testnumber": 30
        }}
    }]
}
```

I wanted to perform Add, Edit/Update and Delete operations on this json data using AngularJS.

I have done the following:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
       <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
       <script src="app.js"></script> 
      </head>
      <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Add</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myTestJson.MyTest" >
                  <td>{{value.Main.static.name}} </td>
                  <td><a ng-href="editName.html">Edit</a></td>
                  <td><button id="button1"  ng-click="add(value.Main.static.name)">Add</button></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <br>
        <table border="1" class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr  ng-repeat="name in jsonNames"  >
              <td>{{name}}</td>
              <td><button id="button1" name="singlebutton" ng-click="delete(name)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-hide="myTestJson.MyTest.length">
              <td colspan="3">
                <p>No Names</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

editName.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <title>Edit and Update JSON data</title>
        <div>
           <table><tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myTestJson.MyTest.Main.dynamic" >
                  <td><label>{{key}}: </label> 
            <input placeholder="" type="text" ng-model="value">
                   </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button value="Update and Save" id="saveButtonId" ng-href="index.html" ng-click="finishEdit">Update/Save</button>
        </div>
    </html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $http ) {
     $http.get('test.json').success(function(response) {
        $scope.myTestJson = response;
       // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

      $scope.add = function (){
        alert("add is called");
        //$scope.myTestJson.push($scope.jsonNames);
        $scope.myTestJson.push($scope.myTestJson, jsonNames);
      };
       $scope.delete = function (index){
        $scope.myTestJson.splice(index,1);
        alert("JSON Name is deleted");
      }
     $scope.saveUpdate = function (index) {
            $scope.myTestJson[index] = $scope.dynamiceditedModel;
            $scope.edited = -1;
        };
        //$scope.dynamiceditedModel=$scope.myTestJson;
    });
  });
```

a. If I click on `Add` button: then respective JSON Name data should be added in my second table.

b. If I click on `Edit` button: then respective selected JSON Name "`dynamic`" field options should be editable (on `editName.html`) and then should be saved on clicking of Update/Save button(and then it should be redirected to `index.html`).

c. If I click on `Delete` button: then respective JSON Name should be deleted.

I have created [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z3WKnia4feMwBzCc6U5Y?p=preview). I request you all please help me regarding this how can I perform these operations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I bet there is a way how to parse and edit files with JS, however this is not regular way how you wanna use Angular. Usually you just get data from JSON and store it in some variabile which can work with:)

Comment: @Andurit, thanks for your reply, yes, I am storing the json data in $scope.myTestJson only.

Comment: what should happen if you click add?

Comment: @Sravan, if Click on Add, then respective JSON Name data should be added in my second table.(for example if we click on Add for "TestName1" then "TestName1" should be added under Name column in my second table, so that "TestName1" will have it's own data(static and dynamic fields data) and I can download it.

Comment: You just need to display the name in the second table when clicked on add?

Comment: @Sravan, Yes only name should be displayed, but it should hold it's data: "Main": {
            "static": {
                "name": "TestName1"
            },
            "dynamic": {
            "testkey01": "testkey01data",
            "testkey02": 40,
            "testkey03vals": [1, 1, 1]
        }} , this data I can download using download option(in json file).

Comment: Do you need the dynamic value to be changed in test.json file?

Comment: @Sravan, yes if we click on Edit button, then it should display to edit "dynamic" field options only for the selected Name. Like: if I click on Edit for "TestName1, then it's dynamic fields should be displayed and can be editable and can be saved in my editName.html("testkey01": "testkey01data",
            "testkey02": 40,
            "testkey03vals": [1, 1, 1])

Comment: @Sravan, yes, if edit and update with some new values means that respective selected Name data should be changed and hence I can add that Name on clicking on Add so that respective Name will be having new updated values(we need to change dynamic values in test.json).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123955/discussion-between-dhana-and-sravan).

Comment: @Sravan, Can I know anything please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the answer based on our discussion. It may be lengthy since I worked on all the files and added them,

First of all,

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="test.json"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">    
  <ui-view></ui-view>    
 </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
    app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $http,$state,$stateParams,filterFilter,$rootScope) {
        $rootScope.jsonNames = []
        $rootScope.filteredArray = []
        console.log($rootScope.myTestJson)         
        if($rootScope.myTestJson == undefined)
        {
            $http.get('test.json').success(function(response) {
                $rootScope.myTestJson = response;
            })
        }    
           // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

          $scope.add = function (name){
            alert("add is called");
            //$scope.myTestJson.push($scope.jsonNames);
            $rootScope.jsonNames.push(name);
            console.log($rootScope.jsonNames)
          };
           $scope.delete = function (index){
            $rootScope.jsonNames.splice(index,1);
            alert("JSON Name is deleted");
          }

          console.log($stateParams.edit != undefined)
          if($stateParams.edit != undefined){
            console.log($rootScope)
            $rootScope.id = $stateParams.edit
          }
         $scope.saveUpdate = function (index) {
                console.log($rootScope.myTestJson)
                $state.go('home')
            };
            //$scope.dynamiceditedModel=$scope.myTestJson;

    });
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'main.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl',
        })
        .state('edit', {
            url: '/edit/:edit',
            templateUrl: 'edit.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl',
        });

});
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Add</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myTestJson.MyTest" >
        <td>{{value.Main.static.name}} </td>
        <!-- <td>{{$index}} </td> -->

        <td><a ui-sref="edit({edit: $index})">Edit</a></td>
        <td><button id="button1"  ng-click="add(value)">Add</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br><br>
  <br><p>Second Table:</p>
  <table border="1" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr  ng-repeat="(key, value) in jsonNames"  >
        <td>{{value.Main.static.name}}</td>
        <td><button id="button1" name="singlebutton" ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-hide="jsonNames.length > 0">
        <td colspan="3">
          <p>No Names</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**edit.html**

```
<title>Edit and Update JSON data</title>
  <div>
    {{myTestJson.MyTest[id].dynamic}}
     <table><tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myTestJson.MyTest[id].Main.dynamic  track by $index"  >
            <td><label>{{key}}: </label> 
      <input placeholder="" type="text" ng-model="myTestJson.MyTest[id].Main.dynamic[key]">
             </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <button value="Update and Save" id="saveButtonId" ng-click="saveUpdate()">Update/Save</button>
  </div>
```

**The json file is same as it is.**

pls integrate this, I will explain it where you want.

Comment: Yes, Excellent Brother !! It's working fine as per my requirement !! I really Thank you for your help and support !!

Comment: I have one query, May I know if you are available?

Comment: I am discussing it in the chat ! Like for example if I change my json structure(from "Main"  to Main1, Main2 and Main3)then what would be written in ng-repeat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123955/discussion-between-dhana-and-sravan

Answer (score 1):

You have billion of mistakes there. You should definitly start with something really basic and try it one by one :). We all learn and it take time to practice so don't take it wrong.

I fixed your add / delete mistakes and you can find working example of it in here

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/fPjll5WqgrWCR00TUoaK?p=preview
```

To be more specific what did I change:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('TestCtrl',function($scope, $http ) {
      // created new scope variabile
      $scope.table2 = [];
         $http.get('test.json').success(function(response) {
            // removed functions from this scopes, there is no reason for it
            $scope.myTestJson = response;
         });

          $scope.add = function (name){   
            // giving argument to this function
            // pushing it to new variabile instead of old one
            $scope.table2.push(name);
          };
           $scope.delete = function (name){
             // argument name you was sending was just name
             // you need to find index of it in array
             index = $scope.table2.indexOf(name);
             // and then splice it
             $scope.table2.splice(index,1);
          }
          $scope.saveUpdate = function (index) {
                // I didnt get to this..
                $scope.myTestJson[index] = $scope.dynamiceditedModel;
                $scope.edited = -1;
            };            
      });
```

In html i changed this:

```
  // You had whole second table out of any controller
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I can see only name on Add option(that's fine), I can see only added name, but it should have it's own data too. Like if we click TestName1, then it should hold: "Main": {
            "static": {
                "name": "TestName1"
            },
            "dynamic": {
            "testkey01": "testkey01data",
            "testkey02": 40,
            "testkey03vals": [1, 1, 1]
        }} , this I need to see on my console in some object format and can download in json file. Could I know about it please.